# Change risk.table.title font size in ggsurvplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I do not know how to change the size of the title of my risk table, `risk.table.title = "RISK"`

Data:

```
library(survival)

data <- data.frame(time  =c(1,2,3,4),
                    status=rep(c(1,0),4),
                    n=c(1,2,3,4),
                   grp = c(1,1,0,0))
obj  <- Surv(time = data$time, event=data$status) 
fit <- survfit(obj ~ grp, data = data)
```

Now I fit the Kaplan-Meier curve:

```
myplot <- ggsurvplot(
  fit,
  data = data,
  xlim = c(0, 60),
  break.x.by = 20,
  xlab = "Day",
  ylab = c("Survival probability"),
  risk.table = "abs_pct",
  font.x = c(12, face = "bold"),
  font.y = c(12, face = "bold"),
  font.tickslab = c(12),
  font.legend = c(12),
  risk.table.title = "RISK", 
  risk.table.col = "black",
  size = 1
)
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set and adjust the theme used for the risk table via the `tables.theme=` argument. To change the size of the title font you could do:

```r
library(survminer)

ggsurvplot(
  fit,
  data = data,
  xlim = c(0, 60),
  break.x.by = 20,
  xlab = "Day",
  ylab = c("Survival probability"),
  risk.table = "abs_pct",
  font.x = c(12, face = "bold"),
  font.y = c(12, face = "bold"),
  font.tickslab = c(12),
  font.legend = c(12),
  risk.table.title = "RISK",
  risk.table.col = "black",
  size = 1,
  tables.theme = theme_survminer() + 
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 40))
)
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to change the font type?

Comment: Sure. The font family you be set via `family=` in `element_text()`.